# Events are being tracked but no corresponding Goals (Goal conversions are equals zero)

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goal-tracking, event-tracking, analytics-events

I have a website with universal analytics in the head section and recently I setup Google tag manager to check if I would be able to resolve the issue with no success. My Tracking code looks like

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I created an AJAX based event pushing the following onclick event **functions** in 3 different forms

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Category [Form]', 'Action Name [1,2,3]', 'Label Tag [1,2,3]',1);
```

and in google analytics I created 3 Goals using the same Category/Action/Label for each of the 3 different Action-Labels

Inside my Google Analytics Behaviour->Event->Overview Report I can see all 3 events being traked, but in the Convertion->Goals->Overview Report all 3 have zero records.

Any ideas why this is happening? should I set up the goals again (after event tracking implementation)?

Comment: Did you set up GTM, Google Analytics or both? We need to see an example of your implementation on html code also.

Comment: Can you part screenshots of your goal configuration?

Comment: Yes, I Will get the html code, in the google analytics view the goal configuración Is an standard custom events setup with their respective category, action, label and value. E.g I am not using any quotation marks for two words Action named

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem myself and I would like to post the answer in here just in case someone goes through the same struggle.

Basically the Goal value did not match the value in the function. The Goals configuration page looked like this

[image]

I noticed the message under the "Use the Event value as the Goal value for the conversion" (Answered "YES")

> If you don’t have a value defined in the condition above that matches your Event tracking code, nothing will appear as the Goal Value.

You can either:

1. Try to match the function parameter with the same value as in the goal configuration or
2. Set The Answer to "NO", delete the value in both the function and the Goal configuration and assign the value for the conversion in $USD or to whatever your currency is (My Choice)

Comment: can you please explain how you delete the value in both the function and the goal configuration?

Comment: @user89755 check the goal configuration page screenshot above, there the value is se to “Greater than: 1”, simply delete that value of one, from the input text field. The “function “ is the script event you sent with the category, action, label and value parameters e.g. ga(sent, event, ‘category’,’action’,’label’,1) ... remove  ,1